# How to make a html template in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to use Dreamweaver for coding and with it, you were able to make a template to use for all pages, let's say menu etc...
I am coding HTML site and I want to reuse some of the code for entire page like footer, header, menu etc....
do I need a plugin or can I do it inside visual studio easily?

Comment: dreamweaver was able to update all the pages derived (multiple levels) from the template if you change the template, VSC does not have this capability out of the box, Maybe in a extension. Much better to use a template engine in the web backend

Comment: which template engine is that? how other people code html sites? If they want to change a link on all pages, they cant just edit all pages individually. Dreamweaver template is great, but I dont want to use two programs to code....

Comment: don't serve static pages. it depends on your language and framework, search for `template` and `framework name`. If dreamweaver template is great use Dreamweaver